# Updating WordPress plugin database

Tags: wordpress

Assuming that a plugin is already in use by people on the app-store, is there an easy way to force a database update while keeping the data that the user has? Having to wipe the database and remove all records is not exactly an ideal scenario.

The specific operation in mind is adding a column with a known value for existing records.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Yes, update the plugin version and in the new code add your new column.

Comment: Where would you include the code to add the new column? I previously had the database instantiated in the activate-plugin class that would check to see if the table existed or not, and act accordingly.

Comment: You will find answers here : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67345/how-to-implement-wordpress-plugin-update-that-modifies-the-database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's many ways to do it. One way is to compare plugin version and do the migration there. Once it's done update the version so it doesn't get repeated.

```
function plugin_update() {
    global $plugin_version;

    if ( get_site_option( 'plugin_version' ) != $plugin_version )
        plugin_updates();


}

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'plugin_update' );


function plugin_updates() {
    global $wpdb, $plugin_version;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'thetable';

    $wpdb->query(
        "ALTER TABLE $table_name
         ADD COLUMN `count` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL
        ");

    // update option
}
```